# Items that cloned by Sortable JS which have Select2 inside them are not working

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-select2, sortablejs

Items that cloned by Sortable JS which have Select2 inside them are not working.

I tried to destroy and re-init but it didn't seem to work.

Jquery Code

```
            $("select").select2();
        function cleanDrop() {
        $(".dropped-area").removeClass("unsetter");
        $(".dropped-area").addClass("setter row");

        $(".placeholder-drop").removeClass("d-flex");
        $(".placeholder-drop").hide();
        }
        function onEndStyle() {
        $(".dropped-area > div").removeClass("col-lg-3 col-md-4");
        $(".dropped-area > div").addClass("col-12 new-style");
        }
        new Sortable(pullContainer, {
        group: {
            name: "shared",
            pull: "clone",
            put: false,
        },
        sort: false,
        animation: 150,
        chosenClass: "xdd",
        ghostClass: "zaa",
        cancel: ".select2",
        onMove: function () {
            cleanDrop();
        },
        });
        new Sortable(targetContainer, {
        group: {
            name: "shared",
            pull: "clone",
        },
        draggable: ".new-style",
        handle: ".handle",
        animation: 150,
        onAdd: function () {
            onEndStyle();
        },
        });
```

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/Xteripus/pen/wveoPqM?editors=1010)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately select2 is creating some custom internal IDs, You must destroy and recreate select2 after cloning / drop.